# show dialog seamlessly after opening an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, themes

I want to show a dialog (kind of splash screen) when my application is opened. Therefore I put a create and show dialog into onCreate(). The dialog opens indeed but first, the empty activity (white background) is shown.

There must be a possibility to prevent that empty screen to be shown? A lot of apps have a behaviour like that. I would like to have the dialog as the actual first screen to be shown to the user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159702/android-show-spinning-wheel-dialog-while-loading-data

Comment: Have a look at this http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/

Comment: code is here: https://github.com/nobnago/Anki-Android/blob/da0f20af28865067821f29c21a23e83049d1af04/src/com/ichi2/anki/DeckPicker.java

Comment: but it's not a matter of things beeing done before the dialog is shown. The problem is, that even if I show the dialog directly after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) and before setContentView(), there will a an (empty) activity first. So I need to get rid of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be better if we have code to see tasks taking time as per general solution

[Android SplashScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979524/android-splashscreen)

[Show spinning wheel dialog while loading data on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159702/android-show-spinning-wheel-dialog-while-loading-data)

http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/

Comment: <resources>
    <style name="Theme.Shelves" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_shelf</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>