# Progress Dialog is not spinning enough in asynctask in android

Tags: android, dialog, android-asynctask, progress

I am using `progress dialog` in my `Asynctask` class. I put progressdialog.show() on `onpreExecte()` method of asynctask and dismissing the dialog in `onPostExecute`. My problem is the wheel in dialog is stops after 2-3 seconds but my background process is working. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? I want to spin the wheel until the background process is over.

Comment: can u post your code?

Comment: post your code then we will solve your problem.

Comment: post your code so that we can help you out

Comment: protected void onPreExecute() {super.onPreExecute();
   progress_dialog.show();
   progress_dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
   
  }  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
  progress_dialog.setCancelable(true);
json_string_category=json_parser.getJsonStringfromUrl(jsonurl + area_id_async);
   
 
  return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
  {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onPostExecute(result);
   progress_dialog.dismiss();
   
   doing image loading from web is done here.
  
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check tutorials how to do asynchronus task in Android:

- [link](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/)
- [link](http://jyro.blogspot.com/2009/11/android-asynctask-template.html)
- [link](http://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/create-a-custom-progress-bar-using-asynctask)
- [link](http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/android-async-task/)
- [link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html).

And here are some other StackOverflow questions that are similar:

[Progress dialog problem in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096584/progress-dialog-problem-in-android)
 
[Progress Dialog on open activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254139/progress-dialog-on-open-activity)
 
[Progress Dialog while starting new activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231438/progress-dialog-while-starting-new-activity)
 
[Android: Progress Dialog spinner not spinning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119676/android-progress-dialog-spinner-not-spinning)
 
[Updating progress dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524472/updating-progress-dialog)
 
[android: showing a progress dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017375/android-showing-a-progress-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but it seems to me that starting the progress dialog INSIDE the AsyncTask causes the dialog to work on the AsyncTask thread, instead of the UI thread.

I suggest moving the `progressdialog.show()` to just before you call `execute()` in your Activity.

Comment: On second thought, this probably isn't the case.  Dialogs MUST occur (at least in some important part) within the UI thread.  Please ignore this answer; it was just a stab in the dark.